# How to build a List Card having scroll bar in Teams bot similar as Who bot?

Tags: .net-core, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I am developing MS Teams bot using .NET Core.
Who bot from Microsoft has this List card with scroll bar.

[image: List card sample image]

I didn't find the code to implement it just like we have Thumbnail card, Hero card, etc.
Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you link to the code you're talking about regarding thumbnail cards, hero cards, etc.? There don't seem to be any samples or SDK code regarding list cards, but does Manish's link give you what you need?

Comment: I didn't get any reference code how to implement one List card using C#.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't get hung up on whether or not there's a built-in C# class that represents the schema you're using. There are many REST API's and JSON schemas out there and not all of them are going to have C# classes prebuilt into NuGet packages for you to install. Each Bot Framework SDK ultimately uses the [Bot Framework REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-overview) behind the scenes, so every activity you send gets converted to JSON strings anyway. When it comes to creating C# objects that correspond to JSON, here are some options:

1. You could create your own C# classes
2. You could read the JSON as a string and parse it into a [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm)
3. You could create a `JObject` manually using [C# object initialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreateJsonCollectionInitializer.htm)

Everything you need to know about list cards is in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#list-card) Manish already linked to. Here's some sample code I used to send a list card using option 2:

```cs
var json = File.ReadAllText("Resources/listCard.json");

var attachment = new Attachment
{
    ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.teams.card.list",
    Content = JObject.Parse(json),
};

await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(attachment));
```

I created a JSON file based on the [JSON example](https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#example-of-a-list-card) from the docs. Note that you can't just copy the whole example and expect it to work because it's an attachment object and you want just the card. You want to use just the "content" from that example, so it would look like this:

```json
{
  "title": "Card title",
  "items": [
    . . .
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is helpful.

Comment: @ParthShah - Please remember to accept the answer

Comment: @KyleDelaney Hi I wonder when I want to open the task module from the list card. what is the type of the item and the tap type and value?

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang - I can't really answer that because you haven't explained what you want the user to tap on to invoke the task module. I'm guessing you could just put an `invoke` card action in the buttons array. Please refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-bots#bot-framework-card-actions-vs-adaptive-card-actionsubmit-actions) for examples of how to invoke task modules.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try List card. Since it's json card you need to send it as an attachment.

```
 private static Attachment CreateListCardAttachment()
    {
        // combine path for cross platform support
        string[] paths = { ".", "Resources", "listCard.json" };
        var listCardJson = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(paths));

        var listCardAttachment = new Attachment()
        {
            ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.teams.card.list",
            Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(listCardJson),
        };

        return listCardAttachment;
    }
```

Please use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#list-card) json code for reference.

Comment: The OP specified in their question that they wanted to use List Card, so they’re going to need more than that to answer the question. The link might do it, but as you surely know Stack Overflow doesn’t accept link-only answers. Can you expand on how to implement one for this scenario?

Comment: I know that List card is the answer to it but I don't know how to implement it.
Microsoft.Bot.Schema namespace only exposes ThumbnailCard, HeroCard but not ListCard. Where is it?

Comment: @ParthShah :  Microsoft.Bot.Schema doesn't contain this card since it's not part of bot framework SDK but more related of MS Teams Ecosystem. I have modified my answer above to use .json file to post the list card as an attachment.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is helpful.